# can VoIP support ussd application?

Tags: voip, ussd

I have a VoIP Internet connection and I am trying to develop a ussd application. I don't know if ussd is supported on VoIP though. So do I need to get E! lines or is the VoIP enough?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: yes, basically we had E Carrier (E1) lines to entertain an IVR and SMS service. Now we have installed a VoIP line that supports 1000 calls simultaneously  but I do not know if the VoIP technology supports a USSD application as well. Hope its clear enough.

Comment: USSD platforms are made of 2 parts: the gateway that connects in MAP to the HLR (E1 or Sigtran/IP) and talks to the movile network and the app server that often the GW queries through HTTP and that carries the business logic of the application. GW is hosted by the Telco Operator who also declares the short code on the HLR. The app server might be operated by you. In all cases you need to have a commercial agreement with your Telco. USSD is decorrelated from having or not having VoIP.